# Volume of Revolution Verification

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> **Question:**
>
> A region in the $xy$-plane is bounded by the $x$-axis, the lines $x=1$, $x=2$ and the curve $y=2x^2 +1$. Find the volume obtained by rotating the region around the $x$-axis.

I did the following:

---

$$\text{Volume of a slice} \approx \pi(2x^2 +1)^2\Delta x$$

Thus we can find:

$$\text{Total Volume} \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \pi(2x_i^2 +1)^2\Delta x_i$$
Now let $n\to\infty$ as $\Delta x \to 0$, then we can find

\begin{align}\text{Total Volume} &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \pi(2x_i^2+1)^2\Delta x_i  \\ &= \int \limits_{1}^2 \pi(2x^2 +1)^2 \mathop{dx}\end{align}

---

Is this correct?

I have not done Volumes of Revolutions in a very long time, as I am now used to doing them with multiple integrals.

Comment: The representation of the volume as an integral is correct.  In a standard calculus course, one would just write it down without the Riemann sum preliminaries.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Is there any way in which I can improve the "set up" of the volume integral (i.e the Riemann sum etc)?

Comment: If you intend to write down the approximation using Riemann sums, you need to define what you mean by the $x_i$, $\Delta x_i$.  But in most contexts, one just writes down the integral.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Thank you! I am planning on tutoring this year and would like to show the students the process of how to get to the integral in order to try and form a good understanding of where it comes from. I would indicate the $x_i, \Delta x_i$ on the graph for them. :)

Comment: I think it is better to say that a thin cross-section "at" $x$ has volume about $\pi(x^2+1)^2\, \Delta x$, or even $\pi(x^2+1)^2\,dx$, and for the volume we "add up" (integrate) from $1$ to $2$. That sort of informal reasoning will take care of many standard "Physics" applications.  Riemann sums come (and historically came) later.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - that sounds like a much better way of explaining it and will certainly help, since a lot of the students are more comfortable with Physics, so that should definitely help them grasp the concept much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct. In general, you can skip all the summations and delta's and directly use the formula for a (continuous) function $f(x)$ running from $x=a$ to $x=b$:
$$\pi \int_{a}^b {f(x)}^2 dx$$

Comment: Thank you! I am planning on tutoring this year and would like to show the students the process of how to get to the integral in order to try and form a good understanding of where it comes from.

Comment: That is great! You can show only once the infinitesimal delta summation approach for the Riemann integral for any function and then let them use the formula freely. A nice example is $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, defined on $[-1,1]$ and gives you the volume of a sphere of radius $1$.